# Table Relationships for Property Bags Configuration

Tags: database-design, relations

I am creating a database table setup for user preferences in my application based partially on this [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204902/database-design-for-user-settings) and while I created the tables and foreign keys, I can't seem to figure out the relationships of these tables. The attached screenshot is the DB design and below is what I currently believe are the correct relationships

[image: user preferences]

`user` to `user_preference` = one-to-many

`user` to `preference` = many-to-many

`user_preference` to `user` = many-to-one

`user_preference` to `preference` = many-to-one

`user_preference` to `allowed_preference_value` = many-to-one

`preference` to `allowed_preference_value` = one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

You've captured the relationships in the design that you've referenced correctly.  The one nuance that isn't clear in what you've documented is that the relationship from `user_preference` to `allowed_preference_value` is optional, meaning that `user_preference.allowed_preference_value_id` is nullable.  It's not clear whether you've accounted for this or not, but it matters if you have user preferences which are not selected from pick lists but are instead taken from another source.

Your design also omits the preference *values* themselves.  I'm assuming that was a deliberate choice to focus on the relationships and gloss over the rest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The `user_preference` foreign keys are not nullable.